# Where should I delegate this UITableView to?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, delegation

I'm building a scrollable grid layout in iOS.

The hierarchy is as follows:

```
(MyController) UITableViewController
  - Parent Table View (UITableView)
    - "Horizontal cell" (UITableViewCell)
      - Sub Table View (UITableView)
        - Sub table view cell (UITableViewCell)
        - Sub table view cell (UITableViewCell)
    - "Horizontal cell" (UITableViewCell)
      - Sub Table View (UITableView)
        - Sub table view cell (UITableViewCell)
        - Sub table view cell (UITableViewCell)
    - "Horizontal cell" (UITableViewCell)
      - Sub Table View (UITableView)
        - Sub table view cell (UITableViewCell)
        - Sub table view cell (UITableViewCell)
```

What I'm trying to decide is whether the sub table view should delegate to it's parent Horizontal cell or to delegate to the main view controller.

My gut instinct would be to delegate to the view controller but the tutorials and examples I've seen for this approach all delegate the sub table view to it's parent table view cell.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, the horizontal cell's table view will be rotated -90* so that it's cells scroll horizontally to create a grid effect.

Comment: `UITableView` inside `UITableViewCell`? Why not everything in single `UITableView`?

Comment: Each row should have it's own set of cells that scroll horizontally

Comment: And how are you going to make UITableView to scroll horizontally?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Actually I just wanted to make sure you know what you're going to do)